# Reinstall Ubuntu button missing

Tags: 14.04

I remember once upon a time reinstalling Ubuntu and keeping my personal files using the live CD. Now I'm trying to do this again because my installation has become corrupted, but the installation CD gives no such option. Ideas?

Note: I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the "something else" installation option from the Live CD and then using reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 on the Ubuntu partition as mount point. This method preserved my Home folders files.